# Use a second canvas for drawing an animation in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, mapcanvas

I want to implement an animation of flowing rivers on top of an Openlayers map. My doubts are if I simply should make a new canvas and position it on top of the map or if there is a more elegant way using a OL layer?

What I try to do is similar to [this example](http://andywoodruff.com/blog/the-rain-on-terrain/) using Leaflet. This animation is done using canvas *lineTo()* function with an interval and works with pixel coordinates drawn on a second canvas. Leaflet offers [map.createPane()](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/#custom-pane) function which then handles the positioning for you and allows you to link a second canvas to the map.

[image]

I have the animation working in OL ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/w8fpj2z4/)) drawing it directly on the map canvas. The problem now is that I have to set the canvas *globalAlpha* property to simulate the trail effect which makes all other layers disappear. Another possibility would be to draw a semitransparent rectangle over the whole canvas, with the same negative effect of making disappear everything else on this canvas:

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I could get it working positioning a new canvas on top of the map, but then I would have to handle all the interactions by myself.

So does there exist something similar to Leaflets *map.createPane()* function or any other possibility to use a second canvas linked to the same map?

PS: just to make it clear, I want something like [that](http://maps.tnc.org/migrations-in-motion/#5/33.046/-88.110).

PPS: There is a new [OL plugin](https://github.com/sakitam-fdd/wind-layer) based on windjs which looks really promising.

Comment: something like http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html ?

Comment: yes, but with trail effect. and the only way to make this trail effect I know is drawing a almost transparent rectangle over the whole area which then has the effect that also the background disappears. Here's a test using the OL example: https://jsfiddle.net/geraldo/dqjukx8v/ I just added lines 21 to 23 and 45+46 to show the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you give [ol-ext](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/) a try? They have a lot of cool stuff you can do on the map and this way you won't require an additional canvas or transparent layers.

The closest thing I can see they have that might work for you is this one [here](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map.featureanimation.path.html).

Comment: Actually [this one](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map.interaction.tinkerbell.html) is technically more close what I want to do. I use a control for the animation, but can't manage to make the trail effect happen. What this example shows is the combination of postcompose event and render function. So based on this example it should be possible to make the desired effect.